# Write a sequence that is a geometric and arithmetic progression at the same time.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I thought to write this system

$$\begin{cases} y_n = y_1 \cdot q^{n-1} \\ y_n = y_1 + (n+1)d \end{cases}$$

How do I solve it?

Comment: consider a trivial case of a constant sequence

Comment: $\{1,1,1,\cdots\}$ a constant sequence with common-difference $0$ and common ratio $1$.

Comment: The second equation in the system ought to be $y_n = y_1 + (n - 1) d$. (Substitute $n = 1$ in both sides to see why.)

Comment: The [constant sequence](http://oeis.org/wiki/Constant_sequences#:~:text=Constant%20sequences%20are%20sequences%20for,n%20%3C%20i%20m%20a%20x%20.) is the only sequence which is both an A.P. and a G.P.

Answer (score 1):

If $y_1 = 0$ or $q = 0$, the first equation gives $y_n = 0$, which is a solution iff $d = 0$. So, henceforth suppose $y_1 \neq 0$.

Note that for any such sequence, we must have $q > 0$, as otherwise the series alternates sign and so could not be arithmetic.

Setting the expressions $y_n$ equal to one another and rearranging gives (for $n > 1$) that
$$y_1 \cdot \frac{q^{n - 1} - 1}{n - 1} = d,$$
which must hold for all $n$.

If $q < 1$, the limit of the l.h.s. is $0$, so $d = 0$ and hence $y_1 = 0$, which we treated above.

If $q = 1$, the l.h.s. is $0$ and hence $d = 0$.

If $q > 1$, applying l'Hopital's rule gives that the limit of the l.h.s. is $\infty$, unless $y_1 = 0$, which must be the case, and hence again $d = 0$.

In each case, we get $d = 0$, so the only possible sequences are the constant sequences $$y, y, y, \ldots,$$ but these are geometric with $q = 1$ and $y_1 = y$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows easily that you must have 
$$y_1(q^{n-1} - 1) = (n-1)d$$

You have to find solutions $q, d, y_1$ to the previous equation that do not depend on $n$

for example $y_1 = 0$, $d = 0$ works for all $q$ and the resulting sequence is $y_n = 0$

Or $q = 1$, $d = 0$ and the resulting sequence is $y_n = y_1$

if $y_1 \neq 0$ and $d \neq 0$ you get

$$q^{n-1} = \frac{(n-1)d}{y_1} + 1 \implies q = \sqrt[n-1] {\frac{(n-1)d}{y_1} + 1}$$
which depend on $n$ so it is not acceptable. Hence the only solutions are those I wrote above